# How to remove the empty space between the bands in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm working on a report in Jasper for Java. I put the table header in the **title band**, the content in the **details band** and the summary part of table in the **summary band** (these are all different tables). The same Dataset is used in all three tables.
[Here is the scheme of bands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVXeU.png)

However, when I print it to pdf (via Java REST service) this gap appears  between tables. [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCcp6.png)

Tell me please how to remove it? Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stretch the row height to full title band.

Also adjust the height of the band using below code snippet:

```
 <band height="<your_couple_of_lines_of_text_height>">
 <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} < 2]]></printWhenExpression>
 the_conditional_header_content_here
 </band>
```